# I can not edit in the gridview

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I am using linq to entity i have added the gridview but it's not editing and when i debug it doesn't access the method GridView5_RowUpdating().. here it's the code of the grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerId" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            onrowupdating="GridView5_RowUpdating">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerId" HeaderText="CustomerId" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have Required field validator when i am trying to insert manually when i removed the Required field validator can someone tell me what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to implement the [RowEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx) event on the gridview to enable editing, MSDN definition:

> Occurs when a row's Edit button is clicked, but before
>   the GridView control enters edit mode.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="gvCustomers" 
        runat="server" 
        OnRowEditing="gvCustomers_RowEditing">
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Re bind the grid view
}
```

Now if this event is not being fired when you click the **Edit** link on your grid view it means that there is some validation logic on the page which is preventing a post back.

The best way to get rid of this issue is to set the `ValidationGroup` attribute, for the validation controls causing trouble(not the gridview):

```
<div id="insertEmployee">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
    </div>
```